# How to fill Angular state data components from a single server call?

Tags: angular, rxjs

The problem is that I have an admin panel with a left side menu that when the user clicks on,  the components in the middle window changes, all this leads to a server call and receiving a large **JSON** with the status of the new state, whether new window title, user characteristics information(user name, surname...), let's say a lot of state data in a single call (I think it is not a good design implementation but this functionality cannot be changed, boss orders).

Once I received the **JSON**, I would like to fragment the data filling it into `services` properties with `observables`, for example `userService`, `documentService`.

I have to create for each property of a service that are approx 20 properties a `Subject` for each of them, and `subscribe()` to them, in the component that needs it (in order to see the new state in the view) leads to performance problems or it's better to have a kind of model added and update for example in property groups in a single `Subject`?

What is done in these cases that you get so many state properties and you have to distribute them among all the components without using any state storage?

Comment: you might want to share some code to help people address your question. It seems you tried to be descriptive on your question, which is good. You also could make it a little better with paragraph breaks and shorter sentences.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are making a single service call, and getting back a fairly large JSON response, and then want to create several services, each of which is responsible for part of that data.

There's really nothing wrong with getting all of the data that you need in one http call. It may actually be more efficient, because the most expensive part of an HTTP request is the overhead of setting up the HTTP connection.

If you really want to go with the design that you seem to be suggesting, you can certainly create a service for each part of the model that you want to maintain separately, create a Subject for each piece of data in each service, and subscribe to them all.

However, you mentioned "without using any state storage".
My question is why not use state storage, e.g. Redux or ngrx/store ?
If you do all of this in discrete services, with Subjects and subscriptions, you're going to be pretty much re-inventing what a state store does, probably just not as well.

I speak from experience. I have an application where I thought that it just wasn't worth adding a store to my application (I had never used one at that point), and wrote something similar to what you suggest. The amount of data grew over time, and I wound up adding the store anyway (Redux in my case), and when I was done, I wished that I had used the store to begin with.

Comment: Yes, you have understood correctly.  We can not use a store because we are a little behind in this project and we can not spend much more time but after what you said I will look for later projects.  Therefore there can be no performance problem if I have many subscriptions in one component?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my current project we too had to get multiple component data on first call. My approach was to create an eventservice where all data events funnel. The starting component subscribes to the first get request, then notifies the eventservice of received data. All other components subscribed to that event parse the data only applicable to that component. Each sub component being responsible for only a part of the data. They change gui state as needed and persist changes.

Once user refreshes the page the cycle starts over.

It is ultra fast , reliable, and fully componentized. Single Responsibility Principal in practice.

Comment: That was my first approach, but if the component data changes then doesn't notify the others. Could you show some code interface from eventservice?

Comment: No other component should care about each other's modification. E.g A person object contains an address. The address part has nothing to do with person part, when it changes the address component does the persistence. Theoretically no sub component needs to notify upward or to its container or others. If it does need that the SRP principal is not right.